# modify or create SaveFile dialog in wpf or winform

Tags: wpf, winforms, savefiledialog

For my application I would like to use the SaveFile dialog box. on SaveFile dialog i just want to let the user select location to save and hide the file name and save as type. How do I achieve this? 
can I still use the save File dialog box that is in Microsoft.Win32? or I  have create my own dialog window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the File Dialog might be what you want. It only let's the user select a folder. You would then be free to name the files yourself.

```
Dim fb As New FolderBrowserDialog
fb.Description = "Select the Folder"
fb.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer
Dim dlgResult As DialogResult = fb.ShowDialog()

If dlgResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    savefolder = fb.SelectedPath
End If
```

There you go.

Comment: @ Asryael           Thank you so much. I was confused when you said file dialog. I was looking at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.aspx